# Gaussian curvature of an axisymmetric surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Given an axisymmetric surface $r=R(z)$, the expression for the mean curvature I came across is $$\frac{1}{R(1+R_z^2)^{1/2}}-\frac{R_{zz}}{(1+R_z^2)^{3/2}}.$$ Is the Gaussian curvature: $$\left(\frac{1}{R(1+R_z^2)^{1/2}}\right)\left(-\frac{R_{zz}}{(1+R_z^2)^{3/2}}\right)$$

Any insight in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: The summands are the principal curvatures for a surface of rotation, so the mean curvature is one-half your first expression, and the second expression is indeed the Gaussian curvature (though it's customary to simplify the denominator).

Comment: Thank you very much.